# How to scroll CCLayer horizontally in Android cocos2dx?

Tags: android, scrollview

I am working on Android game application and need to scroll cclayer horizontally. I have main activity and have multiple layers added on main Activity. I am not getting how to use CCScroller or scrollview in cclayer android cocos2dx

Answer (score 0):

You can create a scrollview like the following:

```
CCScrollView *scrollView = CCScrollView::create(CCSizeMake(200, 120));
scrollView->setContentSize(CCSizeMake(400, 120));
scrollView->setPosition(CCPointZero);
scrollView->setDirection(kCCScrollViewDirectionHorizontal);
this->addChild(scrollView);
```

An then you can add sub layers into it like:

```
CCLayerColor *layerColor = CCLayerColor::create(ccc4(255, 0, 0, 155), 200, 120);
layerColor->setPosition(ccp(0,0));
scrollView->addChild(layerColor);

CCLayer *layerColor = CCLayerColor::create(ccc4(0, 255, 0, 155), 200, 120);
layerColor->setPosition(ccp(200,0));
scrollView->addChild(layerColor);
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Do you have any idea, where can i find CCScrollView class?

Comment: Refer: cocos2dx/extensions/GUI/CCScrollView/CCScrollView.cpp

Answer (score 0):

If you can't find ScrollView class, you should add 2 line:

> #include "cocos-ext.h"
>
> using namespace cocos2d::extension;

Hope this help!